# Purpose of URI parameters in the path component

Tags: uri, url-parameters, query-string, path-parameter

We know that it is possible to pass parameters in the *path component* of URIs using the syntax `;param=value`. I wonder what this is good for, taking into account that parameters can also be passed in the *query component*.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax) doesn't even mention the possibility of including parameters in the path component.

Another [site](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/) mentions this possibility but it also adds that it is almost never used:

> Each of the path segments can contain parameters which are separated from the segment by a ; (semi-colon) character e.g.:
>
> > `http://www.blah.com/some;param1=foo/crazy;param2=bar/path.html`
>
> The URL above is perfectly valid, although this ability of path segments to hold parameters is almost never used (*I've never seen it personally*).

I found an explanation on Stackoverflow "when to use @QueryParam vs @PathParam" but it seems to me that any parameters could be passed in the query component, making path parameters redundant. And above all, I don't have an idea why somebody would use the above syntax to pass parameters in the URI.

The example quoted above also raises the question whether `param1` and `param2` have anything to do with `some` and `crazy`, respectively. Or why is it useful that we can include parameters in the path component?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For example it's used in Angular2 to isolate parent and child route parameters.